# How to Format English Date in Japanese with ERA

Tags: java, simpledateformat, cjk

I want the new Japanese ERA Date as "R010501", whereas I am getting "R151".

I am using the `com.ibm.icu.text.DateFormat` package to get the date format

```java
Date dtEngDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2019-05-01");

com.ibm.icu.util.Calendar japaneseCalendar = new com.ibm.icu.util.JapaneseCalendar();

        com.ibm.icu.text.DateFormat japaneseDateFormat = japaneseCalendar.getDateTimeFormat(
                 com.ibm.icu.text.DateFormat.SHORT, -1, Locale.JAPAN);      

        String today = japaneseDateFormat.format(dtEngDate);
System.out.println("today is:" +today.replaceAll("/", ""));
```

Output: today is --> R151.
Expected Output: today is --> R010501

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you did other than me but I just downloaded the `com.ibm.icu` library from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomibmicu442jar.htm and basically copied your code.

```java
import com.ibm.icu.text.DateFormat;
import com.ibm.icu.util.Calendar;
import com.ibm.icu.util.JapaneseCalendar;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Date dtEngDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2019-05-01");
        Calendar japaneseCalendar = new JapaneseCalendar();
        DateFormat japaneseDateFormat = japaneseCalendar.getDateTimeFormat(DateFormat.SHORT, -1, Locale.JAPAN);
        String today = japaneseDateFormat.format(dtEngDate);
        System.out.println("today is: " + today.replaceAll("/", ""));
    }

}
```

I'm getting `today is: 平成310501` as console output and I guess this is what you are looking for. So I guess there is something wrong with your `com.ibm.icu-4.4.2.jar`.

Maybe consider retrying to download the latest version from the link I used and adding it to the modules/projects dependencies.

Comment: Hi Nicola, Thank you for the answer. YES, the month is coming as expected. But if I use the JAR that you have mentioned the ERA name ["平成"] is not changing. As you are aware, from 01-May-2019, a new ERA in Japan will start which is called as "Reiwa" [令和]. These changes are not part of the JAR that you have shared. Just FYI, I have used the JAR from [link](http://site.icu-project.org/download/64) which has the latest changes.

Comment: To further add, I am aware this can be done using **some String functions** (which I am reluctant to do). But if you / someone can help me get this format using the DateFormat / SimpleDateFormat class, then it would be helpful.

Comment: Uff.. I was not aware of this change... I will dig further into it.

Comment: I guess there is no way with DateFormat. Even `japaneseCalendar.get(JapaneseCalendar.YEAR);` still gives me `31` and not `1` so I really don't know what is messed up. I guess they changed their `format`-function and therefore you most likely have to use String functions. I know this is not that elegant but I really don't see another solution.

Comment: Thank you. Will update if I get some breakthrough in this.

Answer (score 1):

## `java.time.chrono.JapaneseDate`

You don’t need an external dependency for the Japanese calendar. It’s built-in, in the [`JapaneseDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/JapaneseDate.html) class.

**Beware:** Only the most recent versions of Java know about the new [*Reiwa* era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reiwa).

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("GGGGGyyMMdd", Locale.JAPANESE);
    LocalDate isoDate = LocalDate.parse("2019-05-01");
    JapaneseDate japaneseDate = JapaneseDate.from(isoDate);
    System.out.println(japaneseDate.format(dateFormatter));
```

Output from this snippet on Java 11.0.3 is:

> R010501

Five pattern letters `G` gives the narrow form of the era, just one letter (here `R` for Reiwa).

On Java 9.0.4 I got `H310501`. So it seems that it will work correctly if you are able to upgrade your Java. Meno Hochschild reports in a comment that he got the correct result on Java 8u212, so you may not need to upgrade to a new major version if only you’ve got the newest minor upgrade within your major version. I don’t know if there’s a way to upgrade only the calendar data in an older Java version, it might be another thing to investigate.

BTW don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed (the former in particular notoriously troublesome) and long outdated. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It’s so much nicer to work with.

**Link:** [Oracle Tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining the use if java.time.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce it even with Java 8u212, but the internationalization is insufficient. For example: `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL).withLocale(Locale.JAPANESE).format(japaneseDate)` produces: "2019年5月1日" while correct and complete localization would mean this (example using my lib Time4J): `ChronoFormatter.ofStyle(DisplayMode.FULL, Locale.JAPANESE, JapaneseCalendar.axis()).print(
                PlainDate.of(2019, 5, 1).transform(JapaneseCalendar.axis())
            ) => "令和元年5月1日水曜日" (not easily possible in Java 12 or 13, see the usage of gannen year)

Comment: Thank you, @MenoHochschild, for your insightful comment. I still think that when the asker asks for `R010501`, this shouldn’t be too hard with java.time. Otherwise [your Time4J](http://www.time4j.net/) is certainly an option to consider too.

Comment: Gannen year (= first year of era) can only be printed in standard java by use of old class `SimpleDateFormat`. But using `java.time`-package requires a hand-written map of texts being passed to `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` which is very awkward. Japanese people are aware of such limitations and not so enthusiastic about the new Japanese calendar in `java.time.chrono`.

Comment: I have edited to show how to obtain `R010501` as you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But when pasted the above code I am still getting the old Era (i.e. Heisei H). I have used the following packages. **java.time.LocalDate, 
java.time.chrono.JapaneseDate, and 
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter**
Please let me know if I have missed anything.

Comment: @AmitUnakal On Java 9.0.4 I get `H310501`. On Java 11.0.3 I get `R010501`. Seems only newer Java versions “know” about the new era.